# Lectures on Semantics in Generative Grammar

Tags: formal-semantics

I do not know if my question is pertinent, but I would like to ask if you know any places where to find video lectures on formal semantics in linguistics, specifically approaches treated in Heim and Kratzer "Semantics in Generative Grammar". Though I think written notes and similar materials is a lot, I wnted to ask you if there were videos on those topics, too.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL51-f__wSXvdBa0QFNT80lcoqupTamnKd follows the Heim & Kratzer theory and appears to be of decent quality.